# Bibliography entry color change

Tags: bibliographies, color

How do I change the color of the following line in bibliography?

```
\bibitem{Alexander} J. W. Alexander, \textit{Functions which map the interior of the unit circle upon simple regions}, Ann. of Math., \textbf{17}(1915-1916), 12-22.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried using `\color` after `\bibitem`?

Comment: In case the the previous comment does not solve your problem, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)